# Commune with Nature as a barbarian

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, barbarian, rituals

My barbarian has reached 10th level which says she can cast Commune with Nature as a ritual. The PHB says one of the animals I chose for my totem spirit or aspect of the beast appears to convey the information I need. 
I have different animals so

1. Do I get to choose which one I want to ask the question to?
   or
2. Do I just ask the question and one of the animals will appear with my
   answer?

   If I get the choice, is there somethings an eagle can tell me that a bear can't and vice versa?

Answer (score 4):

### You can choose the facts:

[commune with nature](https://www.dnd-spells.com/spell/commune-with-nature-ritual) or PHB 244:

> You briefly become one with nature and gain knowledge of the surrounding territory.
>   In the outdoors, the spell gives you knowledge of the land within 3 miles of you. In caves and other natural underground settings, the radius is limited to 300 feet. The spell doesn’t function where nature has been replaced by construction, such as in dungeons and towns.
>
> You instantly gain knowledge of up to three facts of your choice about any of the following subjects as they relate to the area:
>
> - terrain and bodies of water
> - prevalent plants, minerals, animals, or peoples
> - powerful celestials, fey, fiends, elementals, or undead
> - influence from other planes of existence
> - buildings
>
> For example, you could determine the location of powerful undead in the area, the location of major sources of safe drinking water, and the location of any nearby towns.

It would make sense that for flavor purposes your DM would choose which spirit animal delivers the message, possibly with your suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean by "flavour"?

Comment: Basically, for storytelling purpose, the animal to deliver the desired information.

Comment: Okay. I see. I know the DM values to way to story is told as do I.

Comment: Is this the official rule or an opinion?

Comment: The *effects* of the spell are as described. The visual appearance of the spell, an animal showing up, is *not tied* to the effects.

Comment: I think your comment T.J.L. makes more sense. If you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it.